# Global overload delete[] not called in third-party libraries

Tags: c++, memory-management

I'm trying to learn about memory pools in [C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B) for better speed and debugging capabilities. I've been following the approach found here: http://oroboro.com/overloading-operator-new/. So I've overloaded `new`, `new[]`, `delete`, and `delete[]` like this:

```
inline void* operator new     ( size_t size ) { return myAlloc( size ); }
inline void* operator new[]   ( size_t size ) { return myAlloc( size ); }
inline void  operator delete  ( void* ptr   ) { myFree( ptr ); }
inline void  operator delete[]( void* ptr   ) { myFree( ptr ); }
```

I like that third-party libraries are directed to this version of `new`, but I ran into a problem. I am making a [DirectX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectX) application that uses DXUT. I compile DXUT separately from my project. Eventually it calls:

```
std::unique_ptr<D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA[]> initData( new (std::nothrow) D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA[ mipCount * arraySize ] );
```

Once this unique pointer goes out of scope, it crashes on a call to  `delete[] _Ptr`, which did not go through my overloaded operator. I tried debugging my memory pool implementation by adding a `int* dummy = new int[10]; delete[] dummy;` in my `main`. Building the project gave an error, but clean-building worked fine. To my surprise, everything worked, including the DXUT line that was crashing!

Question 1: What exactly happened when I added the debugging line that fixed the issue? I guess for some reason my operator delete[] was not known until I called it in my own application code? Is this guaranteed to fix the problem or is it just dumb luck?

Question 2: I noticed that the `new (std::nothrow) D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA[ mipCount * arraySize ]` did not call my `operator new[]` directly, but eventually called my `operator new` (no brackets). It still calls operator `delete[]` on the pointer. Does this pose an issue? Do I have to add the appropriate overload such that my `operator new[]` is called or is this behavior fine?

For reference, the `operator new[]` overload that was called was:

```
void * __CRTDECL operator new[](::size_t count, const std::nothrow_t& x)
_THROW0()
{ // Try to allocate count bytes for an array
    return (operator new(count, x));
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Question 1: What exactly happened when I added the debugging line that
>   fixed the issue? I guess for some reason my operator delete[] was not
>   known until I called it in my own application code? Is this guaranteed
>   to fix the problem or is it just dumb luck?

§3.2 [basic.def.odr]/p4:

> An inline function shall be defined in every translation unit in which
>   it is odr-used.

It sounds like that your compiler didn't generate code for global `operator delete[]` since it's not used in your main translation unit and is marked `inline` (meaning that the compiler can assume that any translation unit that uses them will have a definition of them). However, your separately compiled library doesn't have a definition of those functions, and you end up using the default ones from the standard library. Making them non-`inline` should fix the problem.

> Question 2: I noticed that the `new (std::nothrow) D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA[ mipCount * arraySize ]` did not call my
>   `operator new[]` directly, but eventually called my `operator new` (no
>   brackets). It still calls operator `delete[]` on the pointer. Does
>   this pose an issue? Do I have to add the appropriate overload such
>   that my `operator new[]` is called or is this behavior fine?

The default versions of both throwing and nonthrowing versions of `operator new []`, as well as the nonthrowing version of `operator new`, are specified to call the throwing version of `operator new` to obtain memory. So you are safe there. However, your `operator new`'s definitions are likely wrong. They must return a valid pointer or throw an exception. Returning a null pointer is not allowed.

Comment: Removing inline and putting the code in an implementation file instead of the header worked! I wonder why the link I copied that from didn't mention anything about it.